# Can the Arduino Cellular Shield Access the Internet?

Tags: arduino, cellphone, website

My phone has an internet plan. I took it's SIM card and put it on the Cellular Shield (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9607) for Arduino, and I was wondering if I can configure the shield to access the internet. I think they have other shields, but I want to know if I can use the Cellular one.

There is not a lot of data on the web that I could find so I was wondering if anyone has done this before.

Comment: A question like this typically invites "vote to close" pretty quickly. There is no link provided to the product in question, and the question is too vague: Shows no research before asking the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SparkFun cellular shield certainly can access the internet.

The very page linked in the question, contains a discussion post by DaleR, a member on that site, saying:

> I managed to get this Board Working and connect to www.google.com over TCP/IP and HTTP.

The message and responses to it touch upon some issues faced, and resolutions thereof.

I believe that should address the question adequately.